# Amazon Lex v2 Welcome message

Tags: python, aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex

hello everyone I almost finished a bot with lex v2 that uses lambda, I did the integration using the kommunicate client to do before, but now I need the chatbot to start with an intent automatically, this is my first problem.
Also I would like to know if on lambda in the answers there is a way to send a response that makes an elicit slot, and then after 5 seconds send another to move to confirmation intent on lex v2.. I tried with time and asyncio, but it seems that the code does not go on, I can only get the first answer with the slot elicit, I wish that after about 5 seconds I refer to confirmation intent on lex v2, this is my code:

```
   if carFound is not None:
                    # if resp['total'] < 30:
                    #     print('Conferma intento')
                    #     carDialog = {
                    #             "type": "ConfirmIntent"
                    #             }
                    # else: 
                    #     print('Filtri args')
                    #     carDialog ={
                    #         "type": "ElicitSlot",
                    #         "slotToElicit": "Args"
                    #         }
                response = {
                    "sessionState": {
                         "dialogAction": {
                             "type": "ElicitSlot",
                             "slotToElicit": "Args"
                             },
                        "intent": {
                            'name': intent,
                            'slots': slots,
                            "state": "Fulfilled",
                        }
                    },
                    "messages": carFound,
                 }
```

practically after every call to my api that sends me carFound as a payload with all the machines, I should verify that when resp['total'] and less than 30 I refer in addition to the answers also to confirmation intent after some time.

as i said yet i tried with sleep() function of python, and i still have only the response that has the elicitslot,maybe sleep and asyncio are not well for lexv2...
I verified through the test of lambda, with my inputs that the condition of <30 is true, so the problem is on the response i think.

for the welcome i don't know how i can do, i want that my bot start with the intent Welcome for example, without write nothing on my kommunicate client that is on a website.